# How do I catch buggy requests on a MQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm struggling with an issue in designing a project.

I'm using RabbitMQ to queue "requests" from users. The problem is that my consumers are unreliable. i.e a bad submission could cause the consumer server to crash. This means that if I have a bad submission that's re-queued continuously onto the MQ, all my consumers will crash.

I know about the dead-letter-queue but from what I understand, the consumer itself "rejects" a request and places it on the DLQ. In my case, the consumer processing the request itself has crashed.

How should I be dealing with these requests?

Comment: You should fix your consumer application from crashing. It needs to handle bad/buggy requests and back out such messages. Generally the messaging client APIs route such badly formatted messages to a back out or a DLQ automatically.

Comment: If messaging client is not backing out such messages to back out queue or DLQ, then consumer will need handle them appropriately.